# Password Expiration / DNS Issue

Tags: windows-server-2008, active-directory

Our Windows 2008 Server has AD set to have users change their passwords every 30 days.

When a password expires a user is not prompted to reset it. The user is allowed to login with their expired password as normal. The user only sees that their password is expired when attempting to access a mapped network drive.

The user will receive the error message **Your Password is expired.**

The only ways to rectify this issue is to go to the Network Connection on that users machine and set the DNS to the IP of the server. Usually it is set to automatically obtain DNS address.

The problem with that is once the DNS is set to the IP of the server it causes intermittent internet issues such as web pages timing out and just not loading at all. Error 105 (net::ERR_NAME_NOT_RESOLVED)

The problem seems to be with my DNS configuration or perhaps my gateway but I'm really not sure.

Comment: Do you only have 1 physical location? Are they using vpn? Perhaps cached credentials is allowing this. If many locations then perhaps the DC has not received replication changes yet.

Comment: You can determine if the logon is using "cached credentials" by looking for event 4624 in the security log. Look for "new logon" where the "security id" is the users name. There will be also be a good number of System and Anonymous logons. A Logon Type of 11 indicates a cached logon.See https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa394189%28v=vs.85%29.aspx for list of all logon types.

Comment: Yes this is only one physical location and one server. It definitely seems to be allowing cached logon. Perhaps i should be trying to figure out why I'm getting internet issues when i'm using the IP of our server as the DNS on the workstation.

Comment: Hey Jason, I agree it looks like you're seeing DNS resolution problems. Try using DCDiag to diagnose the issue (from the DC): DCDIAG /TEST:DNS /V /E

Answer (score 0):

What DNS servers are assigned to each client via DHCP? If it's anything other than your AD DNS server then that is the root of your problem and you need to stop doing that. AD domain joined computers should only use the AD DNS servers for DNS. If you're having a problem with internet connectivity/DNS name resolution with that configuration then you need to fix that problem. By assigning non-AD DNS servers to your domain clients you're attempting to fix one problem but you're creating another. Fix the root problem.

Comment: You're absolutely right, I need to figure out the internet connectivity issue when a workstation is using the Domain Server IP in their IP configuration. Right now only when config is set to 'Obtain DNS address Automatically'